Appium element.getText() returns element's accessibilityLabel instead of displayed text on iOS (Flutter App)
The background about my issue , the mobile app i'm testing build using Flutter. I'm using Appium xcuitest driver with webdriver.io and Typescript for the mobile test automation. I have added semantic labels to use as accessibiliy labels in Appium inspector and so far it's working great except I'm not able to get the text from elements instead that accessibility label get returned.
I tried few ways like below to get text but still results same.
await expect(this.emailSuccessTitle).toHaveText('Sent successfully!')
await this.emailSuccessTitle.getText();'
This is the result i'm getting, actually 'emailSuccessTitle' is an accessibility label added through the Flutter semantic label.
Expected: "Sent successfully!"
Received: "emailSuccessTitle"
Iv read some threads regarding this mentioned its related to WDA implementation and most soultions are related React-Native like adding testID = etc. If anyone knows how to overcome this issue for Flutter much appreciated. Thank you!

maybe try other attributes like value or something else instead of text, in appium inspector does it show that text is sent sucessfully or something else

Thank you for the answer @mosaad . I tried using value as you suggested but as shown below a11y id applied to name, label, value.
<XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" value="loginTitle" name="loginTitle" label="loginTitle" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="449" y="245" width="282" height="33" index="3"/>
workaround I did was remove a11y id from text label and use other selector method so text needs to retrieve shows as a11y id. Also found a suggestion to use flutter semantic identifier but our flutter version is old I wasn't able to check it out yet

Btw I found some resources claiming this is a iOS known issue https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/537

I'm adding a workaround I used if anyone comes across this issue also. In the mobile app under the semantic widget, I added both label: and value:. And for the label I used ID and for the value I used the text that needs to assert. This approach helped me to keep  a11y ID cleaner without long string and also able to assert the text. I didn't have the option to update our Flutter version so wasn't able to use flutter semantic identifier.
